# Como fazer contador em "blocos" no Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Gostaria saber como ficaria um contador em uma consulta SQL para a seguinte situação:

Tenho as colunas matricula, data e hora trabalhada onde gostaria de criar outra coluna com o contador onde ficaria uma sequencia somente nos zeros e os diferentes de zeros.

Estrutura da tabela

```
MATRICULA / DATA       / HORA TRABALHADA

005770    | 21/04/2015 | 0    | 1

005770    | 22/04/2015 | 703  | 1

005770    | 23/04/2015 | 485  | 2

005770    | 24/04/2015 | 517  | 3

005770    | 25/04/2015 | 0    | 1

005770    | 26/04/2015 | 0    | 2
```

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de como você quer que fique?

Comment: no 5º registro não seria 2 e dps 3?

Comment: ou tu quer resetar sempre que muda a sequência?

Comment: boa tarde Maicon, teria que resetar a sequencia. o instuido dessa consulta é verificar se o funcionário tem hora trabalhada por sete dias ou mais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu já tive uns problemas com isso de mudar valores conforme a sequência, você vai precisar da função `LAG`, ela serve pra retornar o valor da linha anterior. E depois particiona seus valores.

```
with f1 as
(
  SELECT matricula, data, hora, 
         lag(hora) over (order by matricula) anterior
  FROM funcionario
),
f2 as
(
  SELECT matricula, data, hora, 
         sum(case when (hora = 0 and anterior = 0) 
                    or (hora <> 0 and anterior <> 0)
             then 0 else 1 end) 
          over(order by matricula rows unbounded preceding) as mudou
  FROM f1
)
select matricula,
       data,
       hora,
       row_number() over(partition by mudou order by matricula) as seq
from f2
```

### [SqlFiddle Demo #1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/187f6/31/0)

#### Saída:

```
matricula   data        hora    seq
005770      2015-04-21  0       1
005770      2015-04-22  703     1
005770      2015-04-23  485     2
005770      2015-04-24  517     3
005770      2015-04-25  0       1
005770      2015-04-26  0       2
```

### Explicação:

1º SELECT:

```
SELECT matricula, data, hora, 
         lag(hora) over (order by matricula) anterior
FROM funcionario
```

Vai retornar um select com os valores da linha atual e da hora anterior.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2º SELECT:

```
SELECT matricula, data, hora, 
       sum(case when (hora = 0 and anterior = 0) 
                    or (hora <> 0 and anterior <> 0)
             then 0 else 1 end) 
          over(order by matricula rows unbounded preceding) as mudou
FROM f1
```

Nessa eu agrupo os valores quando são horas atual e anterior = 0 ou então são diferentes de 0.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3º SELECT:

```
select matricula,
       data,
       hora,
       row_number() over(partition by mudou order by matricula) as seq
from f2
```

Utilizo o `row_number` pra ir contando as linhas, **PORÉM** `particionado` pelos agrupamentos feito anteriormente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Fique atento! Se você quiser mudar a `ordenação` precisa alterar em todos `OVER` de todos `SELECT`.

#### Utilizando apenas `row_number` (MS Sql 2008)

```
WITH CTE_RN AS 
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CHAPA ORDER BY CHAPA, DATA) AS RN
    FROM AAFHTFUN
WHERE        DATA  >= '04-01-2015'
AND          DATA  <= '05-20-2015'
)

SELECT
    t.CHAPA,
    t.DATA,
    t.HTRAB,
    CASE WHEN t.HTRAB = 0 THEN 1
         ELSE t.RN - COALESCE((SELECT TOP(1) s.RN
                      FROM CTE_RN AS s
                      WHERE s.HTRAB = 0 AND s.rn < t.RN
                            AND s.CHAPA = t.CHAPA
                      ORDER BY RN DESC), 0)
    END AS seq
FROM CTE_RN AS t
```

### [SqlFiddle Demo #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00106b/5/0)